# PHP: is the eval function safe enough when only alphanumeric characters and operators are allowed?

Tags: php, parsing, security, eval

I am considering the function 'eval' to evaluate a user-generated mathematical expression.

However, I am stuck. I know that eval is safe if I only allow numbers and operators (e.g. pluses, minuses, etc...). However, I'd like to let the user enter functions such as sin(x) or cos(x), hence I need to allow the parser to let letters in.

Is it safe?

Can a user enter malicious code with only alphanumeric characters and the characters {+, -, *, /} (brackets non-inclusive)?

Thank you.

Comment: This example where is safe I think because you use a prefix and call only allowed functions https://github.com/madorin/matex

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe?

hard to say as for that the implementation needs to be seen and it's not part of your question.

so at this point, everything is possible. could be safe, could be unsafe, could be a mess or could be golden.

> Can a user enter malicious code with only alphanumeric characters and the characters {+, -, *, /} (brackets non-inclusive)?

Similar, this depends on many different things, maybe first of all what you would consider malicious code. A code that is able to trigger an error?

Also it can depend on the PHP version. Some older PHP versions allow to use undefined constants that are turned into strings automatically.

As numbers are to be allowed, one allowed character likely is `.`  (dot) which is also the string concatenation operator in PHP and may lead to side-effects you may consider malicious.

see the differences: https://3v4l.org/Jkmj0

---

In your specific case, why not review if the already suggested https://github.com/madorin/matex is a good match for your requirements?

It likely renders the inital "is eval safe" question this time irrelevant as you got `eval` out of the equation.